# Trying to learn json

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to learn how to get data from .json using weather underground api.
I've got this far but this will display the highs an lows for everyday.
How do I get it to display only today's high and low?

```
for today in data['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday']:
     print "High: ", today['high']['fahrenheit'] + "F", "Low: ", today['low']['fahrenheit'] + "F"
```

On the json it looks like its listed under period:1 but when I try

```
 for today in data['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday']['period':1]:
```

I get 
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/API/forecast/q/NV/Las_Vegas.json")

data = r.json()

for today in data['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday']['period':1]:
    print today['date']['weekday'] + ":"
    print "Conditions: ", today['conditions']
    print "High: ", today['high']['fahrenheit'] + "F", "Low: ", today['low']['fahrenheit'] + "F"
```

Comment: can you provide the code that generates the json/dictionary?

Comment: That one belongs to the for statement

Comment: You need to show the json data.

Comment: For instance you can `import json` and then do: `print(json.dumps(data['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday']))`. Share that. If that is large try: `print(json.dumps(data['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'])[:5])`

Comment: @jmkmay idk i seen it on howto page I'm not 100% on if it has a real purpose

Comment: @psyche I edited my post so you can see the whole thing I've done

Comment: @johnsmith But what is you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at `str.format()`. It is a very powerful way of formatting strings in Python. You can pass any object to it and it will read it as a string.

Consider this example:

```
import requests

url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/API/forecast/q/NV/Las_Vegas.json"
data = requests.get(url).json()

print('The forecast contains {} items\n'.format(
    len(data['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'])))

for item in data['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday']:
    print('{}\n===========\nConditions: {}\nHigh: {}F Low: {}F\n'.format(
        item['date']['weekday'], item['conditions'], 
        item['high']['fahrenheit'], item['low']['fahrenheit']))
```

Comment: I like it I'll have to try messing around with that some more. How would you take that same thing and have it only pull today's information instead of all 4?

Comment: @johnsmith You could use break after print